# how to use rstrip to remove first 2 characters of a decrypted string?

Tags: python

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from test2 import display

file = 'Fernet'

message = display


key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet = Fernet(key)
encMessage = fernet.encrypt(message.encode())
decMessage = fernet.decrypt(encMessage)


print("key: ", key)
print("Original string: ", message)
print(("encrypted string: ", encMessage))
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
print(f'decrypted string: =\'[decMessage.rstrip(b'message)]')])
```

I am not able to remove b' from the decrypted string
i tried using rstrip, always get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot "remove" `b'` because it is not even part of the string, it is how python decides to display a binary string. It is like asking how to remove the `.` from the number `1.2`.

Comment: Do you want to remove only the **trailing b** from the right or do you want to remove all the **b** in the string [solution for both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72784115/16177121)

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip()` is for removing white space on the right side of the string.

You've got a syntax error because your quotation marks aren't set correctly. As you can see, `rstrip()` in your code is marked green which indicates that the code thinks that that is part of the string.

Please check out the following material.

`rstrip` - https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rstrip.asp

f-strings - https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax for `F-String` as well as `rstrip`, Also the quotations are also uneven. Use single quotation inside double quotation i.e. `"''"` to prevent using escape symbols i.e. `'\'\''`.

- You've to put expression inside the curly-braces `{ }` for String
  formatting. [learn more](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)
- correct syntax: `myString.rstrip(myChar)` [learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rstrip.asp)

### Correct Way

```py
decMessage = "messagebbbb"
print(f"decrypted string: = '{decMessage.rstrip('b')}'")
>>> decrypted string: = 'message'
```

**If you want to remove all the ***b's*** from the string you can replace ***b** with ***''**** using `replace` function**

```py
decMessage = "mbbesbsagebbbb"
print(f"decrypted string: = '{decMessage.replace('b', '')}'")
>>> decrypted string: = 'message'
```